# How to import a fixed width csv file when lines have different patterns of column size using Python?

Tags: python, csv, import, fixed-width

This dataset has information on two kinds of entities: `companies and persons`. Each line of data identifies the entity by the first two characters: `01 for companies and 02 for persons.`

## Example:

```
0183738293836728NAME OF THE COMPANY - ME                                                                                                                                                   
02837382938367282              22NAME OF THE OWNER,NAME OF WIFE
```

First line is the company and second line is the owner information. Not all of the companies have only one owner and some of the names have commas and periods. When there's more than one owner, it's presented on separate lines, but keeping the ID that follows the first two digits in every line. As you can see, the lines present different types of information, thus the need for different patterns to separate the columns.

I need to import this into PYTHON in a way that afterwards it's possible to do some data analysis using statistics, econometrics, etc... . There are 27 big files with this kind of data. If it's possible to automate the iteration of the individual files inside the same folder, even better.

I tried reading it and separating, as well as with `dataframes`, but haven't been able to make it work. Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the csv module, you should use a normal file read, and then separating each column on each line by yourself(using a custom function that fit your need).

In this case I don't think you should/can use the csv module to do the work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now, I'm importing the file two times, each one of them using one metric to separate the columns. Of course, this is not the best way to do it. I think running a loop line by line, identifying lines by the first two characters and then applying the appropriate column pattern would be the solution. Any ideas on how to do that?